# iBeacon did enter region does not trigger when user turns manually bluetooth on

Tags: ios, bluetooth, ibeacon

I am testing iBeacon region monitoring and doing the following steps.

- 1: **Precondition:** Bluetooth is on in the phone and App is not running
- 2: I turn the beacon on
- 3: The app gets launched following a location event (beacon region)
- 4: I turned the beacon off
- 5: The app is still running and detects the did exit region event
- 6: I then kill the app manually (it is ok to do so, region monitoring will still work)
- 7: I turn off Bluetooth on the phone
- 8: I turn the beacon back on
- 9: I turn on Bluetooth again on the phone
- 10: I expect to... see below (Expected result)

**Expected** result: the app should wake up following entering the region (***I tested this without manually switching the Bluetooth and it works***)
**Actual** result: does not happen.

Why does 10 not happen? Is this a bug in iOS?

Comment: Hey, did you manage to somehow solve this? Have the same problem, when app is manually killed and then turn on bluetooth.

Answer (score 3):

Turning Bluetooth off doesn't usually work as a good way to test monitoring. Enter and exit events only happen when the region's state (i.e., [`CLRegionState`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLRegion_class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CLRegionState)) transitions from "outside" to "inside" (and vice versa). If you turn Bluetooth off, the state goes to "unknown"**[1]** (because how would the device know if you're out or in with Bluetooth disabled), and thus if you switch it back on, and it transitions to "outside" or "inside," it won't actually trigger an event **by design**.

You can test that by implementing the `didDetermineState` method, in addition to `didEnter` and `didExit`. Start with the beacon turned off, confirm via `didDetermineState` that the state is "outside." Turn Bluetooth off, turn the beacon on, turn Bluetooth on. You will see `didDetermineState` with state "inside," but no `didEnter`. (It works the same the other way around, i.e., if you start with the beacon turned on, and turn it off while the iPhone's Bluetooth is disabled. You will see `didDetermineState` "outside," but no `didExit`.)

**Note:** this test only works in the foreground. It looks like in the background, `didDetermineState` is not enough for iOS to wake up the app to handle the event—it needs to be `didEnter` or `didExit`.

**[1]** A little clarification here as well. When you disable Bluetooth, there won't actually be an explicit call to `didDetermineState` with `CLRegionStateUnknown`. This is because I suspect that iOS stops delivering any beacon events when Bluetooth is off. How did I arrive at the conclusion that it really changes to "unknown" then? I added an `NSTimer` that calls `requestStateForRegion` (which in turn forces an asynchronous call to `didDetermineState`) every second. When I turn Bluetooth off, `didDetermineState` calls stop arriving. But as soon as I turn Bluetooth on, these calls resume, and the state is "unknown"—before it changes to "outside" or "inside" depending on the current state of the beacon. Again, per the note above, all of this is with the app in the foreground.

(Same mechanics actually apply when you start monitoring already in range of a beacon. Before you start monitoring, the state is "unknown." When you start monitoring, the state transitions to "inside" our "outside" (depending on whether the beacon is in range at the time when monitoring starts), but this does not trigger `didEnter` or `didExit`. Here too you can verify this with `didDetermineState`.)

Comment: So when the Bluetooth is turned back on the App is not woken up as the state determined is "inside" and iOS has not entered the didEnterRegion event?

Comment: Yes. It looks like `didDetermineState` is not enough to wake up the app into the background. I updated my answer to clarify this, and I also added better step-by-step explanation of how I arrived at this conclusion, so that you can reproduce.